# How do you delete an AWS ECS Task Definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

Once you've created a task definition in Amazon's EC2 Container Service, how do you delete or remove it?

Comment: It is now possible to delete a task definition once you have de-registered. The only thing we need now is deleting empty task definition families.

Comment: @DBX12 task definition families that don't have any task definition revisions will no longer be returned when you call the `list-task-definition-families` API, there's no need to delete empty task definition families

Comment: @goto That is an advancement. I mostly use terraform or the Web UI, so I still see them in the Web UI. So just for "cleaning up completely" you could want that functionality.

Comment: @DBX12 not sure I follow, but assuming you don't have any task definition revisions (`ACTIVE`, `INACTIVE`, or `DELETE_IN_PROGRESS`), then that task definition family won't be returned in the `list-task-definition-families` call. The reason why you might be still seeing that task definition family is because you must have a revision in one of those states/statuses.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170378). Once you de-register a Task Definition it goes into INACTIVE state and clutters up the ECS Console.

If you want to vote for it to be fixed, there is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/685). Simply give it a thumbs up, and it will raise the priority of the request.

Comment: It seems to be solved now, see the [answer of fedonev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589654/11764049)

Answer (score 17):

I've recently found this gist (thanks a lot to the creator for sharing!) which will deregister all task definitions for your specific region - maybe you can adapt it to skip some which you want to keep: https://gist.github.com/jen20/e1c25426cc0a4a9b53cbb3560a3f02d1

You need to have jq to run it:
`brew install jq`

I "hard-coded" my region, for me it's `eu-central-1`, so be sure to adapt it for your use-case:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
get_task_definition_arns() {
    aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-central-1 \
        | jq -M -r '.taskDefinitionArns | .[]'
}

delete_task_definition() {
    local arn=$1

    aws ecs deregister-task-definition \
        --region eu-central-1 \
        --task-definition "${arn}" > /dev/null
}

for arn in $(get_task_definition_arns)
do
    echo "Deregistering ${arn}..."
    delete_task_definition "${arn}"
done
```

Then when I run it, it starts removing them:
`Deregistering arn:aws:ecs:REGION:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/NAME:REVISION...`

Comment: I don't know why this was getting down-voted, it worked for me. Ok, the INACTIVE definitions stay around, but at least things are deregistered..

Comment: I assume because it doesn't do what the OP asked, which is to remove or delete task definitions.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: This is deregistering definitions and misleading at first glance.

Answer (score 14):

#### Feb 2023: [Announcing Amazon ECS Task Definition Deletion](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-task-definition-deletion/)

The [DeleteTaskDefinitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTaskDefinitions.html) API [closes the issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/685) noted in the accepted answer.  As previously, [deregistering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeregisterTaskDefinition.html) a task definition sets it as inactive.  The new API allows you to delete `INACTIVE` task definitions:

```bash
aws ecs delete-task-definitions --task-definitions family:revision

aws ecs delete-task-definitions --task-definitions myInactiveTaskDef:1 myInactiveTaskDef:2 myInactiveTaskDef:3
```

Comment: That's useful. But now how do I get rid of the unused task definition families, which still show up when I remove the `ACTIVE` filter (even though they contain no task definitions)?

Comment: @GarretWilson if all task definition revisions for a task definition are deregistered **and** removed, then the task definition family will also be removed. If your task definition family has any task definition revisions that are `DELETE_IN_PROGRESS`, then the task definition family will be still be returned by the API as `INACTIVE`

Answer (score 8):

There is no option to delete a task definition on the AWS console.

But, you can deregister (delete) a task definition by executing the following command number of revisions that you have:

`aws ecs deregister-task-definition --task-definition task_defination_name:revision_no`

Comment: If you have x number of revisions you will have to run the above command for every single revision. Once all revisions have been deleted, the task definition is itself deleted.

Comment: This does not delete the Task Definition, it simply deregisters a single version of a Task Definition. Once all versions are deregistered (inactive), the Task Definition itself will also be deregistered but it and all inactive versions remain. It looks like AWS do not actually offer a way to delete Task Definitions, which is disappointing.

Comment: I like this solution
Just remove all revisions and task definition will disappear from the list

But I don't like missing space after --task-definition flag :)

Answer (score 7):

Oneline approach inspired by [Anna A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9509388/anna-a) reply:

```sh
aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-central-1 \
  | jq -M -r '.taskDefinitionArns | .[]' \
  | xargs -I {} aws ecs deregister-task-definition \
        --region eu-central-1 \
        --task-definition {} \
  | jq -r '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn'
```

Answer (score 1):

Created following gist to safely review, filter and deregister AWS task-definitions and revisions in bulk (max 100 at a time) using JS CLI.

https://gist.github.com/shivam-nagar/aa79b02b74f616f8714d51e419bd10de

Can use this to deregister all revisions for task-definition. This will result in task-definition itself marked as inactive.

Answer (score 1):

Now its supported
I just went inside the Task Definations and clicked on Actions and click on Deregister and it was removed from the UI

[image]