# Why task definitions are not deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

After deleting cloudformation stack,

below task definitions are still around in `INACTIVE` state:

### [image]

I don't have the option to delete them explicitly.

Why cloudformation service does not delete these resources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you delete an AWS ECS Task Definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045264/how-do-you-delete-an-aws-ecs-task-definition)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as deleting a task definition. You can only `de-register` them and this is what cloudformation is doing. When task is de-registered it goes into `INACTIVE` state.

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deregister-task-definition.html) write:

> At this time, INACTIVE task definition revisions remain discoverable
>   in your account indefinitely; however, this behavior is subject to
>   change in the future, so you should not rely on INACTIVE task
>   definition revisions persisting beyond the lifecycle of any associated
>   tasks and services.

Comment: Does task definition go in INACTIVE state only after de-registeration

Comment: @overexchange I think so, though I can't find any confirmation for this in the docs.